# Im trying to put the image background in render

Tags: rendering, node-editor, 3d-view, 3d-manipulator

I tried to put it in transparent. I follow tutorials but I cant get with the render with the image in the background.
I tried with the nodes but i cant put the layer of the iage background, I will aprettiate help, i need it, thanks.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use an *Input > Image* node, load your image, and mix it with the help of a *Color > Alpha Over*:

[image]